# CarrierWave file upload error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

So I get this error when I click submit with the Carrierwave attachment.

```
enter code here
undefined local variable or method `charle' for #<#<Class:0x25134a0>:0x2512668>
10:   <%= @charle.name %>
11: </p>
12: <div class="field">
13:       <%= image_tag charle.image_url.to_s %>  
14: </div>
15: 
16: <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_charle_path(@charle) %> |

app/views/charles/show.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_charles_show_html_erb__1019061838_19434530_0'
app/controllers/charles_controller.rb:18:in `show'
```

Answer (score 2):

On line 10, `@charle` is an instance variable, whereas on line 13 it isn't. Change it to:

```
<%= image_tag @charle.image_url.to_s %>
```

And it should work.